# Is there any way to ban from closing AHK back-end program?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

My child sometimes would play game, i want to control that,so i set AHK to detect game play , well , he is smart and know how to close it ,like below image , close the AHK icon:

[image: example]

i wonder is there any way to ban from closing AHK file ? or in another word, close it through a password,only i can know that password.

in one words,lock any modify to AHK program thoroughly.

i have come up with the idea to set a higher user to lock that close or change,but i think it may be fruitless

Thanks if you know how to lock that modify.

---------------BTW------------------

(i tried to code a C++ back-end exe file ,but he also know how to close it in the task manager.

i have also tried a back-end screenshot exe by python , but he also know how to close it.)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [OnExit](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnExit.htm) function, if the script is closed you can catch the event and only actually close it when a password is given, if the password is incorrect the script is simply kept running.

Comment: Good answer! In addition, OP could also use `#NoTrayIcon` and compile it with an ambiguous name (such as "svchost.exe") to make it hard to distinguish from an OS process.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the [Menu](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Menu.htm#NoStandard) command to remove the default menu items.

```
password := "secret"
Menu, Tray, NoStandard
Menu, Tray, Add , Exit, MyExit

.
.
.

MyExit:
InputBox, password_input, Enter password, Enter password, HIDE
If (password_input == password)
{
    ExitApp
}
else
{
    Msgbox,% "Wrong password"
}
return
```